# Comparing 2 lists and return difference in a 3rd list .net 4.0

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying compare 2 lists and output the differences in another list.Comparing each property Value based on the CustomerNo.I know this has been asked many times but I cannot seem to find what exactly 
I am looking for ,so please do not rush to say it's a duplicate.

My issue are

1) How can I convert to a hashset to improve perfomance (tried convert to hashset but does not return the same result as the list.

2) how can I return a list of "Differences" .By Difference I mean if a customerNo in 1 list has multiple properties that are different that these should be added to the list

Any suggestions

This is what I have done

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                Customer[] oldCustomersSet =
                {
                    new Customer { CustomerNo="1", Name = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs", City = "London"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="2",Name = "Mark", Surname = "Smith", City = "Manchester"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="3",Name = "Emily", Surname = "Blunt", City = "Liverpool"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="4",Name = "George", Surname = "William", City = "Exter"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="5",Name = "aaa", Surname = "bbb", City = "Exter"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="6",Name = "ccc", Surname = "ddd", City = "Exter"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="7",Name = "Jane", Surname = "Wonder", City = "Exter"},
                };
                Customer[] newCustomersSet =
                {
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="1",Name = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs", City = "London"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="2",Name = "Mark", Surname = "WrongSurname", City = "Manchester"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="3",Name = "Emily", Surname = "Blunt", City = "Liverpool"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="4",Name = "George", Surname = "William", City = "WrongCity"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="5",Name = "aaa", Surname = "bbb", City = "Exter"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="6",Name = "ccc", Surname = "ddd", City = "Exter"},
                    new Customer {CustomerNo="7",Name = "Jane", Surname = "Wonder", City = "ExterMistake"},
                };

                 var firstSet = oldCustomersSet.Except(newCustomersSet);
        var secondSet = newCustomersSet.Except(oldCustomersSet);

                //This returns 6 items (3 old and 3 new)
                var result = firstSet.Union(secondSet).ToList();

                //now find all the differences.How do I match it based on customerNo and write to the difference List?
                List<Difference>diffList=new List<Difference>();

            }
        }

    }

    public class Difference
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public string OldValue { get; set; }
        public string NewValue { get; set; }
    }
    public class Customer : IEquatable<Customer>
    {

        public string CustomerNo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Customer other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
            return string.Equals(City, other.City)
                && string.Equals(CustomerNo, other.CustomerNo)
                && string.Equals(Name, other.Name)
                && string.Equals(Surname, other.Surname);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Customer)obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hashCode = (City != null ? City.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (CustomerNo != null ? CustomerNo.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Surname != null ? Surname.GetHashCode() : 0);
                return hashCode;
            }
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Customer left, Customer right)
        {
            return Equals(left, right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Customer left, Customer right)
        {
            return !Equals(left, right);
        }
```

Comment: Fyi, you don't need to create lists to use `Enumerable.Except`, it works also with arrays.

Comment: Also, isn't `CustomerNo` the property that determines if two customers are equal?

Comment: Edited questions ,yes customerNo is the identifier but then each propertyvalues must be compared and see if they are different

Comment: What if multiple properties are different, do you still want only a single `Difference` then? `Difference` should also contain the identifier `CustomerNo`, otherwise it's useless because you don't know to which customers it belonged.

Comment: if multiple properties are different within for a customerNo than all the each property should have a row with the difference list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the two arrays, so you can use the `Join` extension method.

To actually produce the list of "Differences", create a method that compares the properties of the matching new and old customer.

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
public IEnumerable<Difference> GetDifferences(Customer oldOne, Customer newOne)
{
    var props = typeof(Customer).GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var oldvalue = prop.GetValue(oldOne);
        var newvalue = prop.GetValue(newOne);
        if(oldvalue != newvalue)
            yield return new Difference { CustomerNo = oldOne.CustomerNo, PropertyName = prop.Name, OldValue = oldvalue.ToString(), NewValue = newvalue.ToString() };
    }
}
```

Used like this (adjust as necessary):

```
var result = oldCustomersSet.Join(newCustomersSet, 
                                  o => o.CustomerNo, 
                                  i => i.CustomerNo,
                                  GetDifferences)
                            .Where(d => d.Any())
                            .ToLookup(d => d.First().CustomerNo);
```

produces this result:

[image]

*(Note I added a `CustomerNo` property to `Difference`)*

---

If both of your lists/arrays are sorted and each element at a certain index in the first list corresponds to the same customer at the same indexin the second list, you could also use a simple `for` loop instead.

```
var diffs = new List<Tuple<string, List<Difference>>>();
for(int i = 0; i < oldCustomersSet.Length; i++)
{
    var curDiffs = GetDifferences(oldCustomersSet[i], newCustomersSet[i]).ToList();
    if(curDiffs.Any())
        diffs.Add(Tuple.Create(oldCustomersSet[i].CustomerNo, curDiffs));
}
```

But to know if this is really faster, you'll have to actually test it.

Comment: thanks for your time .prop.GetValue does  not seem to compile.did prop.GetValue(newOne, null);

Comment: again thanks foryour effort. prop.GetValue(newOne, null); I had to add null and tolookup CustomerNo does not exists  in my difference class as property.Is this the fastest way to compare lists? I will have thousands of objects!!!

Comment: Without measurement, I think putting one list into a Dictionary (CustomerNo => Customer) could perform better than a join. If both lists contain the same number of elements (one for each customer), sorting both lists and iterating other them at once would probably the fastet way. But as with all performance question, you would have to measure which is the fastet way to be sure.

Comment: that sounds good could you show me what you mean .both list will have the same number of elements

Comment: not sure if you see this but what about if i wanted to add a condition  to the join what is the structure many thanks